# get the total sum of all domain controllers

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-3.5

I hope someone could show me how to get to total numbers of domains from
my list? I am trying to get the total so I can implement a `progress bar`. I was able to 
get them to count up but unable to just get the sum.

Below is where I am at currently. I am thinking I need to convert dc to int first?

```
public void findalldomains()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> findD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    List<int> mydomains = new List<int>();
    Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
    using (domain)
    {
        StringBuilder tempText = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DomainController dc in
            domain.FindAllDiscoverableDomainControllers())
        {
            tempText.Append(dc.Name);
            tempText.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            listBox1.Items.Add(dc);
            int t = 0;
            int domainCnt = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().FindAllDiscoverableDomainControllers().Count;
            t += domainCnt;
            Console.WriteLine(t);

        }
    }
}
// without loop and list

public static void findalldomains()
{
    int t = 0;
    //  Console.WriteLine(dc.Name);
    int domainCnt = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().FindAllDiscoverableDomainControllers().Count;
    t += domainCnt;
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the number of domain controllers? If so you'd just do `t += 1;` (although you could do it in fewer lines). If not, then what do you want to count within those domain controllers?

Comment: so you are telling me I am that close? :]

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the total number of domains in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying

```
int domainCnt = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().FindAllDiscoverableDomainControllers().Count;
```